# Getting user's location through FB graph API not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm playing around with Facebook API and I'm able to get the user's name, email, birthday and even photo but for some reason I can't get the user's location. The location variable I used to store the location data keeps returning undefined but I'm using my own profile and I made the location public.

I checked out the Facebook documentation but I would like to see a physical example on how to get the location or even other information. 
Here what I tried so far:

```
 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
 var name = response.name;
 var email= response.email;
 var location = response.location;
 var str = '<div>'+ name +'</div>'+'<div>'+ email +'</div>';

str += '<div>' + location + '</div>';
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =str;

},{scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos,user_location'});
```

I checked out other examples and I see people tried:

```
var location = response.location.name;
```

but I get an error saying name is undefined.

Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: `console.log(response)` and see if there is any location there.. location could also be private and will probably not get displayed.

Comment: there isn't any location there, only the default variables facebook gives you

Comment: yeah I set my location to public

Answer (score 0):

Try requesting

```
/me?fields=id,name,email,location
```

and logging the whole response to console. Furthermore, check if you're really using an User Access Token, or an App Access Token (i.e. are you prompted for giving the permissions?)... You need to use an User Access Token with the relevant permissions granted.

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/debug/

Comment: this only gives the current location,How i can get a list all places that i have visited?